# Get google chrome version from remote computers

Tags: powershell

I need to generate a list of installed google chrome version on different computers.
Following the best answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529145/get-chrome-version-for-remote-devices) I came up with the following code:

```
$machines = Get-content -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\machines.txt

ForEach($machine in $machines){
    $Version = gwmi win32_product -ComputerName $machine -Filter "Name='Google Chrome'" | Select -Expand Version
    "$machine - $Version"
}
```

I don't know why, $Version is completely empty and no value is returned. It seems like The script can't find google chrome at all.

Comment: Do your computers support remote wmi (DCOM)?  You can try get-ciminstance instead (WINRM).

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work for me

```
$machines = Get-content -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\machines.txt
ForEach($machine in $machines){
$Version = Invoke-command -computer $machine {(Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo}
"$machine - $Version"
}
```

Comment: An answer should not be a simple snippet of code. Can you add detail about why and how this specific code answers the question?

Comment: the above versions had the right context, but they werent using the invoke-command method in order to send the command out. What was happening was that they were querying the local machine. This code should run as OP wants above. He/she was really close to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$machines = Get-content -Path C:\Users\user\Desktop\machines.txt

ForEach($machine in $machines){
    $Version = (Get-Item (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe').'(Default)').VersionInfo
    "$machine - $Version"
}
```

Comment: But this does not support remote checks, does it?
It just runs the same Command for the number of machines, but everytime without changing the machine.
Maybe add Invoke-Command to it?

Comment: It doesn't check the given machine it checks it again and again on my computer. $machine is not used in the path